# Openpyxl breaking workbook?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I was wondering if anyone could shed some insight into why openpyxl is returning a broken workbook that needs repair.

I have a workbook saved at 'fileloc' that contains some pivot tables and charts. There is a sheet named 'data' that holds a data table (titled: 'Data') that the other sheets depend on.

When I run something as simple as

> load workbook -> save workbook -> close workbook.

openpyxl returns a broken workbook and broken pivot tables.

Any idea on why this may be happening?

Code for reference:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileloc)
wb.save(fileloc)
wb.close()
```

Errors for reference:

```
 - Removed Part: /xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml part.  (PivotTable view)
 - We found a problem with some content...
 - fileloc is locked for editing by 'another user'
```

I'll add that I am the only user. I have also implemented a task kill function to make sure that all excel processes as closed.

Comment: edit: put the wrong sheet name

Comment: The exception is pretty clear: on Windows only one process can work a file at any one time.

Comment: edits for clarity and focus